# Новый элемент в объекте в цикле

Tags: javascript

В коде есть вопрос, куда вводятся количество сотрудников.
И после спрашивается вопрос "Имя сотрудника" то количество раз, сколько сотрудников.
И это заносится в объект

Но почему-то выдается ошибка, жалуется на эту запись

```
mainlList.employers.name[t] = prompt('Имя сотрудника');
```

Код тут:

https://codepen.io/oykhflhm-the-sans/pen/YzJJNGp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`employers` - пустой объект.

При попытке взять несуществующее поле `employers.name` - получишь `undefined`.

Как результат - при попытке установить свойство у `undefined` - получаешь ошибку.

Для решения можно создавать новый объект внутри `employers`

```
mainlList.employers[t] = { name : prompt('Имя сотрудника') };
```

Comment: А как тогда быть? Нужно добавить пустой ключ name в объект?

Comment: @РоманГерасименко в "employers": {  }, добавь "employers": { name: []  },

Comment: @РоманГерасименко добавил пример, как можно решить